# How could depressurizing air generate light?

Tags: electrostatics, visible-light, electricity

At work one night I had to release approximately 40 psi air pressure from a 3/4 inch ball valve. When I first opened the valve I briefly saw a purple colored flash of light come from the tip of the valve. I was able to recreate this effect multiple times, but it only happens right at the tip, and just for a split second when the valve was first opened. Can anyone explain what generated this light?

Comment: Can you specify what the material of the valve outlet is? Purple flashes usually mean electric interactions. Specially because It's "air", it's more probable.

Comment: The valve I believe is cast iron with a rubber gasket. But what you said does make sense because there is a high amount of dust mixed in with the air upon release.

Comment: Yes! Rubber. My hypothesis is that dust particles, exchange charge with the rubber until the electric field is high enough to ionize the Nitrogen around, and ionized Nitrogen, emits purple lights. Nothing disagrees up to here.

Comment: Awesome, that's really helpful information. I'll research further to understand it better but your answer is a good starting point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a confirmation of the mechanism suggested in @AHB's comment: "The flow of gas across the trim of a ball, butterfly, or eccentric disk valve might generate a static charge on the trim. Because these valves inherently do not have a good grounding path from the trim to the valve body or from the valve body to the pipeline, use proper provisions and care for their grounding. Failure to do this might allow a discharge spark between the trim and valve body or between the valve body and adjacent piping..." (http://www.documentation.emersonprocess.com/groups/public/documents/bulletins/d100071x012.pdf) Note that your valve seems to be made of ferrous metal, which is not intrinsically safe (spark-safe)

There seems to be another possible mechanism: "A foreign particle, such as weld spatter, that is being carried in the flow stream and that strikes the valve
trim or the valve body wall might have its kinetic energy transformed into sufficient heat to raise the impinging particle or the material it strikes to its
respective ignition temperature" (same source) At the time of opening, the air velocity (and, therefore, velocity of foreign particles, such as dust) can be of the order of sound velocity.